# How do I include a figure or table into the exercise environment of the Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: floats, environments

I'm currently having an issue with the \exercise environment of the Legrand Orange Book template. After inserting a table into the exercise environment, I get an error which says !LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

How do I format the environment to allow for tables and figures to be inserted into it without the error? Below is what causes the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations
\begin{document}
\section*{Exercises} 

\begin{exercise}
The following measurements have been recorded by a student in their notebook. However, this particular student has not kept a consistent notation scheme and has made a few errors. Comment where you find an error and correct errors where possible:
       \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            10 $\rightarrow$ 23 & 33 $\rightarrow$ 000 & 015$\rightarrow$ 14 \\
            240/77 W            & 21/60 W              & 000/11 E           
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Below are the specifications for the exercise environment:

```
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}
{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}
```

And the box for this environment is drawn with:

```
% Exercise box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you expand your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)),starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you don't want that to float so don't put it in a figure, just replace    `\begin{table}[h!]
        \centering` ..`\end{table}`  by `\begin{center}..\end{center}`

Comment: Thanks, David! That definitely works and is such an easy fix. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want that to float so don't put it in a figure, just replace `\begin{table}[h!] \centering ..\end{table}` by `\begin{center}..\end{center}`